# i am unable to start new project on ionic even after installing nodejs ,cordova and ionic

Tags: node.js, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I successfully installed the npm,cordova and ionic on my laptop. Still on using the `ionic start iweather tabs` command, I am getting error msgs which I am not able to understand. please help me create a new project.

- node version:9.3.0
- ionic cli :5.5.1

errors are:

```
Build failed with error code: 1
        npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
        npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted                                                                                                                                         {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
        npm ERR! errno 1
        npm ERR! node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
        npm ERR! Exit status 1
        npm ERR!
        npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall script.
        npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output a                                                                                                                                        bove.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

[image: these errors are showing up.]

Comment: What version of Node, ionic cli?

Comment: node version:9.3.0 ionic cli :5.5.1

Comment: try the LTS version of node... That is what the https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/installation/ says

Comment: thanks! LTS version worked.!!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to stackoverflow.  Can you [edit] your question to include your errors as text rather than as a screenshot?  It's policy here not to to use images for this purpose, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500/3744182) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why.

Answer (score -1):

Try this Ma be npm might not be installed properly try to uninstall it and install npm again.

```
rm -rf node_modules/
npm install
```